# Can a node module return a full path to one of its files?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'm pretty new with Node.js and currently implementing a node module that contains a zip. After installing (postinstall) the zip is extracted to a subfolder of the module. Moreover, the main.js script offers to callers a method that returns the full path to one of the extracted files.

The structure of the module look like this:

```
module_A
|- package.json
|- lib
|  └ postinstall.js
|- resources
|  └ ide.zip
|- extracted
|  └ ide.bat
└- main.js
```

So far the requirement seems "easy", however I'm running out of ideas on how to return the full path the the extracted file. Currently my `main.js` script look like this:

```
const path = require('path');

exports.getServerBatch = function() {
    return path.resolve('/extracted/ide.bat');
}
```

when using the module in another project ...

```
C:\projects\myproject\
              |- package.json (includes dependency to module_A)
              |- node_modules
              |  └ module_A
              |     |-main.js
              |     |-extracted
              |         └ ide.bat
              |     ...
```

... and debugging with VSCode, the returned path looks like the following:

`C:\Users\<my_user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\extracted\ide.bat`

instead of:

`C:\projects\myproject\node_modules\module_A\extracted\ide.bat`

If I call the method from another place, the path changes. This makes me think that the full path depends always on where the application is being executed.

Is there a way of returning the full path I need without using the execution path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `path.resolve()` function resolves the given `path` relatively to the `process working directory` which is in your case `C:\Users\<my_user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code` since vs code started the program in that location.

There is a global called `__dirname` which is the folder the file is located in.

You could try this in `main.js`

```
const path = require('path');

exports.getServerBatch = function() {
    // join concacinates paths. Handy for being crossplattform. I suggest to use it 
    // always for putting paths together.
    return join(__dirname, 'extracted', 'ide.bat');
}
```

##### Note:

Using `__dirname` could cause issues when using bundlers like `webpack` OR `pkg`. Some modules permit the usage of `__dirname` and always refer to using `process.cwd()` which is the programs working directory.

Comment: Just at the same time! I've also found the same that you suggest. Thanks a lot for the note. I'll mark this as the answer :)

Comment: Pretty nice :) Almost in the same second yes:)
Use it with caution.. You may want to restructure your program logic..

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of more research I found a solution that seems to work fine:

```
module.exports.serverPath = path.join(__dirname, 'extracted/ide.bat');
```